# Filter objects in python list on the basis of string value

Tags: python

Hi I have a data like this

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/f1/s1.csv' , 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f2/s2/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/f_4/f_5/file.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f3/s3/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/file4.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name' : 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/s5/s6/file4.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)}
       ]
```

I want to get files in each folder with minimum path for example
in  `folder1` there is only 1 file then it will come same way.
in  `folder2`  2 path carrying a file for example `root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3`  and this path `root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/f_4/f_5` so I want to get minimum here . and a 3rd path aswell exist in `folder2`   `'root/folder2/f3/s3/file.csv'`  but it will come as it is. and folder3 will as well get file with minimum path like  `root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/file4.csv`

**Expected output**

```
data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/f1/s1.csv'},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f2/s2/file.csv'}, 
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/file.csv'},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f3/s3/file.csv'},
        {'name': 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/file4.csv'}
       ]
```

**Tried till now:**
I am trying to get paths with minimum slashes but not sure how to check for each sub folder etc for example did this

```
data_dict = {}
for item in data:
    dir = os.path.dirname(item['name'])
    if dir not in data_dict:
        item['count'] = 1
        data_dict[dir] = item
    else:
        count = data_dic[dir]['count'] + 1
        if item['last_modified'] > data_dict[dir]['last_modified']:
            data_dict[dir] = item
        data_dic[dir]['count'] = count

result = list(data_dict.values())
```

Comment: Try this: `[line for line in data if len(line['name'].split("/")) <= 6]`

Comment: @Alexander yes 1 for folder 3  and 1 for folder 1 . but 3 for folder 2 as you can see after `folder2/`  path is different

Comment: @Alexander I want to keep record of sub folders aswell. as for example there could be different files in that sub directories

Comment: @Alexander   `/root/folder2/file.csv`   only as I got file on root

Comment: @Alexander but if there is no file after immediate folder2 then will check all sub directories and will  find files

Comment: @Alexander until I don't get file . for example  `root/folder2/f1`  `root/folder2/f2`  `root/folder2/f3`  so it means I will have to check all three to find files until 5 depths incase there is no file .  if I get file like  `root/folder2/file.csv`  `root/folder2/f1`  I wont go into more depth as got file on root .

Comment: @Alexander in this case if more then 1 file exist even with diff name on same path I will pick the one with  latest  last_modified  date . updated the question please have a look

Comment: @Alexander yes then want both

Comment: @newbiee When you talk about "minimum path" do you mean the length of the path in terms of its string representation or the number of directories? Also, are all paths in the source dictionary guaranteed to start with the same directory name (root)?

Comment: @Stuart number of directories

Comment: @Stuart not necessarily start with root world but will always same for all files whatever name it would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would probably work.

```
import os
import datetime
from collections import Counter

data = [{'name': 'root/folder1/f1/s1.csv' , 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f2/s2/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/f_4/f_5/file.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder2/f3/s3/file.csv', 'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name': 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/file4.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)},
        {'name' : 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/s5/s6/file4.csv','last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 18, 43, 13)}
       ]

results = []

# this next line creates a list of all the paths minus their file name
# and counts them, which shows us how many duplicate paths there are
# so we can filter those based on the timestamp later on
paths = Counter([os.path.dirname(i['name']) for i in data])

for row in data:
    name = row["name"]
    path, filename = os.path.split(name) # split the path from filename

    # this next block is where we check if duplicate counter is greater
    # than 1 and if it is it compares the timestamps and either
    # ignores the entry if it isn't the most recent, or it allows
    # the loop to continue through the rest of the logic
    # if you want to allow to keep 2 files instead of 1 >>>
    if paths[path] > 1:
        # this `lst` contains only the duplicate files paths with different file names 
        lst = [i for i in data if i['name'].startswith(path)]
        # >>> you would run this next line again after removing the
        # the first result from the `lst` above, and allow the script
        # to continue for both of the collected output files.
        least = min(lst, key=lambda x: x['last_modified'])
        if least['name'] != name:
            continue

    # this next loop is where it simply goes through each parent 
    # directory and checks if it has already seen the exact path 
    # as the current path, if it has then it breaks and continues
    # to next item in `data` >>>
    while path:
        dirname = os.path.dirname(path) 
        if dirname in paths:
            break
        path = dirname
    # >>> if it doesn't then that means it is the shallowest copy
    # so it appends the full pathname to the results list
    else:
        results.append({'name': name})

print(results)
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {'name': 'root/folder1/f1/s1.csv'}, 
  {'name': 'root/folder2/f2/s2/file.csv'}, 
  {'name': 'root/folder2/f_1/f_2/f_3/file.csv'}, 
  {'name': 'root/folder2/f3/s3/file.csv'}, 
  {'name': 'root/folder3/f3/s3/s4/file4.csv'}
]
```

Comment: perfectly fine . just 1 case how I can handle  'root/s1.csv' if there is file on root I want to just get this one. and loop ends

Comment: yes these are paths

Comment: and there was a case if there are multiple files in a folder even with diff name then the latest date in last_modified will be picked. can you please check this ?

Comment: yes working . just  same path time update thing remaning

Comment: thanks for helping . just to clarify 1 thing . where in code if I want to add count of the files ignored on basis of   `last_modified` can be added . like  if  there was 2 files in a folder  `root/folder1/sample.csv`   `root/folder1/sample2.csv`  and I keep `root/folder1/sample2.csv`  on basis of  `last_modified`  so I want to keep count:2  in my object .

Comment: or maybe a little explanation as not getting logic of this

Comment: got a issue :( if after root folder are same then it's not working

Comment: @newbiee I need example paths that it wouldn't work on

Comment: seems some data issue . never mind working fine thanks

Comment: getting just issue . can you please check ?

Comment: What am I checking